# Does IO monad become strict when bang pattern is used?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, lazy-evaluation, syntactic-sugar

I expect the following code snippet:

```
main = do
    let !x = [2,3,5,2,3,5,6,7,1,3,0,1]
    begin <- getCPUTime
    let !rx = reverse x
    end <- getCPUTime
    putStrLn $ "Calculation time: " ++ show (end - begin) ++ " ps."
    putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ show rx
```

is identical to the following version:

```
main = do
    let x = [2,3,5,2,3,5,6,7,1,3,0,1]
    begin <- x `seq` getCPUTime
    let rx = reverse x
    end <- rx `seq` getCPUTime
    putStrLn $ "Calculation time: " ++ show (end - begin) ++ " ps."
    putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ show rx
```

Is this true? This is false if `x` and `rx` evaluates to WHNF when "needed", in the first version.

Btw, I want to propose a syntactic sugar for deep evaluation, named "double bang pattern".

Comment: I think they should be equivalent since the IO monad is strict, even if I don't completely understand the GHC guarantees on `seq`, which allows some "reordering" in some cases. `pseq` is stronger, and should guarantee that the code order is indeed the evaluation order, roughly speaking. Note that WHNF is not enough to force all the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific code samples you've given generate identical compiled code.  If you take the following program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module Bang where

import System.CPUTime

main1 = do
    let !x = [2,3,5,2,3,5,6,7,1,3,0,1]
    begin <- getCPUTime
    let !rx = reverse x
    end <- getCPUTime
    putStrLn $ "Calculation time: " ++ show (end - begin) ++ " ps."
    putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ show rx

main2 = do
    let x = [2,3,5,2,3,5,6,7,1,3,0,1]
    begin <- x `seq` getCPUTime
    let rx = reverse x
    end <- rx `seq` getCPUTime
    putStrLn $ "Calculation time: " ++ show (end - begin) ++ " ps."
    putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ show rx
```

and compile it with (with GHC version 8.6.5):

```
stack ghc -- -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques -ddump-simpl -fforce-recomp -O2 Bang.hs
```

you will find in the dumped GHC core that `main1` and `main2` are compiled to exactly the same code, which is actually pulled out into a separate `main4` function:

```
main1
main1 = main4 `cast` <Co:3>

main2
main2 = main4 `cast` <Co:3>
```

**HOWEVER**, in general, the `let !x = ...` construct isn't precisely equivalent to using `let x = ...` followed by `` x `seq` y ``.  For example, the following two IO actions are different:

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = do
  let !x = undefined
  return ()

bar :: IO ()
bar = do
  let x = undefined
  return $ x `seq` ()
```

The first generates an exception immediately:

```
main = do
    print 1
    foo       -- EXCEPTION!
    print 2
```

The second does nothing when executed but will generate an exception if you try to scrutinize it's result:

```
main = do
    print 1
    bar        -- does nothing
    print 2
    x <- bar   -- also does nothing
    print 3
    () <- bar  -- EXCEPTION!
    print 4
```

I believe that after desugaring, `bar` and `foo` are equivalent to:

```
bar = return (undefined `seq` ())
foo = undefined `seq` return ()
```

which explains their different behavior.

Comment: What if you write `seq x $ return ()` instead of `return $ seq x ()`?

Comment: Those are identical to ``x `seq` return ()`` and ``return (x `seq` ())``, so they would behave just like `foo` and `bar`.